# Error says "There is no variable named 'e_level' for 'if e_level == 1:' "

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, undefined

Keeps saying that the variables are undefined when I test it; I have used a variety of different methods to try and fix this problem such as moving the  variables outside of the if's and it works but then I have to do the same for every variable. The other problem with this is then my program does not function correctly and therefore does not serve its purpose. I have done a variety of different programming languages but I am very new to python and I would greatly appreciate any and all help.

```
#collects user input
atomic_number = raw_input("Input elements atomic number: ")

#finds level and electrons in valence level
#good if e_level <= 4 
if atomic_number <= 2:
    e_level = 1
    e_in_v = atomic_number
if atomic_number <= 8:
    e_level = 2
    e_in_v = atomic_number - 2
if atomic_number <= 18:
    e_level = 3
    e_in_v = atomic_number - 10
if atomic_number <= 32:
    e_level = 4
    e_in_v = atomic_number - 18


#construct the electron configuration
if e_level == 1:
    e_c = "1s^" + e_in_v
if e_level == 2:
    if e_in_v <= 2:
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^" + e_in_v
    if e_in_v >= 3:
        e_for_e_c = e_in_v - 2
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^" + e_for_e_c
if e_level == 3:
    if e_in_v <= 2:
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^" + e_in_v
    if e_in_v <= 6:
        e_for_e_c = e_in_v - 2
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^" + e_for_e_c
    if e_in_v >= 7:
        e_for_e_c = e_in_v - 8
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 3d^" + e_for_e_c
if e_level == 4:
    if e_in_v <= 2:
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 3d^10 4s^" + e_in_v
    if e_in_v <= 6:
        e_for_e_c = e_in_v - 2
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 3d^10 4s^2 4p^" + e_for_e_c
    if e_in_v <= 10:
        e_for_e_c = e_in_v - 8
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 3d^10 4s^2 4p^6 4d^" + e_for_e_c
    if e_in_v >= 11:
        e_for_e_c = e_in_v - 18
        e_c = "1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^6 3d^10 4s^2 4p^6 4d^10 4f^" + e_for_e_c

#prints the electron configuration
print(e_c)
```

Comment: Notably, you don't have an `else` clause in your first block, so it's possible to escape that block without `e_level` ever being assigned (if none of the clauses succeed, for instance because of a string not being equal to an int). You should throw an explicit exception or error in this case.

Comment: ...on a similar point, if you'd used an `else: raise Exception("this should never happen")` after that first block, then you'd have known *where* in your code the error was, and could have asked a much smaller question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this line, your input will be a `str`

```
atomic_number = raw_input("Input elements atomic number: ")
```

You need to convert it to `int`.

```
atomic_number = int(raw_input("Input elements atomic number: "))
```

If you compare a `str` to an `int`, the `str` will always be greater.

```
>>> '99' < 5
False
>>> 99 < '5'
True
```

Comment: Wow thanks this worked great now I just need to edit a few other variables and change them to strings. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @tyC2014, changing things that should rightfully be integers to strings won't be helpful -- look at the outcome of `'60' < '9'` for an example of why. You should be changing your strings to integers instead.

Comment: @tyC2014 BE advised that this code will behave pretty strangely in `atomic_number == 1`. All of those `if` statements will evaluate to  `True` and as far as I know hydrogen doesn't have 4 electron levels. You should be using `if` and `elif` instead.